# asp.net sitemap security trimming not working when deployed

Tags: asp.net, security, sitemap

I have basic forms authentication set up and it works just fine locally against IIS express.  When I deploy, the sitemap security trimming stops working (menu items are showing that shouldn't be there).  If I try and go to one of the nodes that shouldn't be there with a user that does not contain the role required, they get kicked back to the the login screen.  Because of that that, I know authentication is working properly.

Another developer I work with has it working just fine locally on his machine as well.  The deployed web server is where it no longer works.

I don't believe there is a problem with any of the markup sine it works locally, so I'll withhold from posting the code.  Every single example on the web matches up with what I have. The code also resides on a network on with no outside access.

No other posts have been found where someone ran into this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After lots of experimenting, we think we narrowed it down.  We are forced to use cookie-less session state on this system and that seems to be the problem.  Our development machines have a major difference in that they have .net 4.5 installed on them.  The production server as well as a few other developers only have .net 4.0 installed. If we allow a cookie, it works just fine.  It seems that the paths are not being handled properly on the 4.0 machines in cookie-less session state which breaks the security trimming. Some more testing is needed to verify this.  Unfortunately updating the production machine is not an option.